# Hibernate: Unknown column in field list

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following error from my Hibernate code:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bulletin0_.bulletin_date' in 'field list'
```

There is no such `bulletin_date` column in my table, nor is there such a name in my model class.  It's just called `date`.  Here is the line where I'm getting the error.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Bulletin where approved = true");
```

Here is my model class (I'm leaving out the getters and setters):

```
public class Bulletin {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="subject")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name="note")
    private String note;

    @Column(name="approved")
    private boolean approved;
}
```

Here is my table definition.

```
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date     | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subject  | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| note     | varchar(2500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| approved | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Date could be a reserve keyword. Try to change the name 'date' to a different name in your entity & DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the wrong column names in my `Bulletin.hbm.xml` file.  When I corrected it, the problem was solved.