# Annotating a ManyToMany relationship: ERROR: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate

I have looked at some different tutorials on how to annotate a ManyToMany relationship.

The error that I am getting when trying to return a list of areas on a user is: **ERROR: Unknown column 'areadao1_.idArea' in 'field list'**

The issue is similar to this post: [Hibernate: Unknown column in field list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976563/hibernate-unknown-column-in-field-list), but the post doesnt give me any answers.

The model:
[image]

So I have areas and users. Each area can have users, or each user can have areas. The naming of the mapping table and columns was auto-generated by mysql workbench.

Here is how my annotated classes look like: 
AreaDAO.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "area")
public class AreaDAO {

    private int idArea;
    private String areaName;
    private AreaDAO parent;

    private Set<UserDAO> users = new HashSet<UserDAO>();

    @Id
    @Column(name="idArea")
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getIdArea() {
        return idArea;
    }
    public void setIdArea(int idArea) {
        this.idArea = idArea;
    }

    @Column(name="areaName")
    public String getAreaName() {
        return areaName;
    }
    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="idArea")
    public AreaDAO getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(AreaDAO parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="area_has_user", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="area_idAarea", referencedColumnName="idArea")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_idUser", referencedColumnName="idUser")})
    public Set<UserDAO> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<UserDAO> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public AreaDAO(int idArea, String areaName, AreaDAO parent) {
        super();
        this.idArea = idArea;
        this.areaName = areaName;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public AreaDAO() {
        super();
    }
}
```

UserDAO.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "user")
public class UserDAO {


    private int idUser;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private Set<AreaDAO> areas = new HashSet<AreaDAO>();

    @Id
    @Column(name="idUser")
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    @Column(name="userName")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name="userPassword")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public UserDAO(int idUser, String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public UserDAO() {}

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="area_has_user", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_idUser", referencedColumnName="idUser")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="area_idAarea", referencedColumnName="idArea")})
    public Set<AreaDAO> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }
    public void setAreas(Set<AreaDAO> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }
}
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

***Edit per @JB Nizet's comments:***

I removed the mapping on the AreaDAO and added:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="areas")
    public Set<UserDAO> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
```

The code that is causing the error is:

```
@Override
    public Set<AreaDAO> getAreas(UserDAO user) {

        Set<AreaDAO> areas = new HashSet<AreaDAO>();

        user.setUsername("admin_vejle");

        try {           
            Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession();

            Query query = session.createQuery("from UserDAO where username = :username");
            query.setParameter("username", user.getUsername());
            UserDAO result = (UserDAO)query.uniqueResult();
            if(result != null)
            {
                areas = result.getAreas();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return areas;
    }
```

More specifically at the getAreas method.

When inspecting the result in Debugging mode, Hibernate will output:

```
Hibernate: select areas0_.user_idUser as user_idU1_3_0_, areas0_.area_idAarea as area_idA2_1_0_, areadao1_.idArea as idArea1_0_1_, areadao1_.areaName as areaName2_0_1_, areadao1_.parent as parent3_0_1_, areadao2_.idArea as idArea1_0_2_, areadao2_.areaName as areaName2_0_2_, areadao2_.parent as parent3_0_2_ from area_has_user areas0_ inner join area areadao1_ on areas0_.area_idAarea=areadao1_.idArea left outer join area areadao2_ on areadao1_.parent=areadao2_.idArea where areas0_.user_idUser=?
mar. 08, 2015 12:31:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
mar. 08, 2015 12:31:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'areadao1_.idArea' in 'field list'
```

Also, a similar exception will be thrown if trying to access the object.

I will let the naming of DAO's be for now.

Comment: First thing you're doing wrong: naming your entities "DAO". A DAO and an entity are not the same thing at all. Second thing you're doing wrong: mapping the bidirectional association twice, transforming it in two separate unidirectional associations. One side must be the inverse side, using the mappedBy attribute. Read the examples in the official Hibernate documentation. Third thing you're doing wrong: asking about an exception, and not posting the complete exception stack trace, along with the code causing that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table area has the column "idAarea". There are two a's in the name: **Aa**rea

I was only using one A in my mappings.

This caused the error.